# CloudFormation Using Fn::Sub inside of Fn::If

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a cloudformaiton template that deploys EC2 instances in multiple regions but makes a slight alteration to the userdata in a particular region. To do this I'm trying to figure out a way to use a map or conditional to make it so if the region is x or y, this is the user data, but if the region is z it's this other thing. The problem is I'm referencing another resource from the template inside of the user data which is causing complications. So within a map it doesn't let you call other functions, it just wants a string, so I switched to trying to use a conditional. Here are some snippets from the code:

```
# accepts a handful of parameters

Conditions:
  IsCleanRegion: !Or
    - !Equals [!Ref "AWS::Region", "us-east-1"]
    - !Equals [!Ref "AWS::Region", "us-east-2"]

Resources: 
  #Creates lambda function
  #creates EC2 SG

  EC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Weather-Website
      ImageId: !FindInMap 
        - RegionToAMIMap
        - !Ref 'AWS::Region'
        - AMI
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::If: 
            - IsCleanRegion
            - - !Sub |
                  #!/bin/bash
                  apt-get update;
                  # Some other things, snipped for brevity
                  #Some HTML/JS put into a file
                      # Inside HTML/JS File
                      const endpointUrl = '${LambdaFunctionUrl}';
                  # More things
              - LambdaFunctionUrl: !GetAtt LambdaUrl.FunctionUrl
            - - !Sub |
                #!/bin/bash
                apt-get update;
                # Some other things, snipped for brevity
                #Some HTML/JS put into a file
                    # Inside HTML/JS File
                    const endpointUrl = '${LambdaFunctionUrl}';
                # More things, some differences from the first one
              - LambdaFunctionUrl: !GetAtt LambdaUrl.FunctionUrl
      # finishes up other EC2 Parameters

Outputs:
  #Some Outputs
```

I think this is all the relevant snippets, but I can't seem to find my way out of an error that says: Template error: variable names in Fn::Sub syntax must contain only alphanumeric characters, underscores, periods, and colons. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your CloudFormation template function calls within calls you'll quickly reach the limit of what CloudFormation templates can do. Try breaking the complex UserData into several smaller parts and joining them together. This can help "flatten" the template and avoid these problems. Here is an example of this from my own code:

```
"Fn::Join":
  - ""
  - - |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
    - echo CMD_VAR=
    - !Ref InputToTemplate
    - |2
      >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
    - |
      yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
    - !Sub "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $?          --stack ${AWS::StackName}         --resource ECSASG          --region ${AWS::Region} || true"
```

You can do much the same with your template:

```
- !Join
  - ""
  - - |
      #!/bin/bash
      apt-get update;
      # Some other things, snipped for brevity
      #Some HTML/JS put into a file
      # Inside HTML/JS File
      const endpointUrl = '
    - !GetAtt LambdaUrl.FunctionUrl
    - |
      ';
      # More things
```